# How to remove empty spaces from a Match formula range?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I intend to remove all the empty spaces from a matrix range applied with the formula "Match ()", as I do to organize only the numbers, thus:{8,8,3,2,19,13,11,6,20,19,2}? 
Would there be any way to organize them like that ?? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain the original order:

```
=INDEX(MATCH($A$1:$A$22,$B$1:$B$22,0),N(IF(1, AGGREGATE(15,6,1/ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$1:$A$22,$B$1:$B$22,0))*ROW($A$1:$A$22),SEQUENCE(COUNT(1/MATCH($A$1:$A$22,$B$1:$B$22,0)),,1,1)))))
```

If you don't have the `SEQUENCE` function, you can use:

```
=INDEX(MATCH($A$1:$A$22,$B$1:$B$22,0),N(IF(1,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$1:$A$22,$B$1:$B$22,0))*ROW($A$1:$A$22),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(1/MATCH($A$1:$A$22,$B$1:$B$22,0))))))))
```

Either will --> `{8;8;3;2;19;13;11;6;20;19;2}`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have no objection to a sorted array, you can use the following formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(15;6;MATCH($A$1:$A$22;$C$1:$C$22;0);ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(MATCH($A$1:$A$22;$C$1:$C$22;0)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If one has Dynamic Array formula FILTER:

```
=FILTER(MATCH(A1:A22,B1:B22,0),ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A22,B1:B22,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Its formula is the smallest of all! it's easier too, but it's a shame that my Excel 2019 doesn't have this "Filter ()" function available